# Xcode, only retrieving addressbook last names with the letter A(and so on)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, addressbook

i am having trouble retrieving the last names of my addressbook. I only want to retrieve last names by each letter of the alphabet.

this is the codes i have so far

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
totalPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

NSString *aString = @"A";

for(int i =0;i<[totalPeople count];i++){
    ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)
    [totalPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
}
```

I dont know what to do after, thank you for looking at this.

now it is like this

```
 ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
totalPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

NSString *aString = @"A";

for(int i =0;i<[totalPeople count];i++){
    ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)
    [totalPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    NSString *firstLetterOfCopiedName = [lastName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    if ([firstLetterOfCopiedName compare: aString options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
        //This person's last name matches the string aString
        aArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:lastName, nil];
    }

}
```

it onlys adds one name to the array, what should i do in order to add it all.
sorry guys, i am fairly new to ios developing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this and store the result in an array or return the result. (Not tested)

```
NSString *firstLetterOfCopiedName = [lastName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
if ([firstLetterOfCopiedName compare: aString options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
    //This person's last name matches the string aString
}
```

You need to alloc the array outside the loop (otherwise it will only ever contain one object), the array also has to be an NSMutableArray (so it can be modified). Here is an example:

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
totalPeople = (__bridge_transfer NSMutableArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

NSString *aString = @"A";

//This is the resulting array
NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i =0;i<[totalPeople count];i++){
    ABRecordRef thisPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)
    [totalPeople objectAtIndex:i];
    lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABRecordCopyValue(thisPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    NSString *firstLetterOfCopiedName = [lastName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0,1)];
    if ([firstLetterOfCopiedName compare: aString options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame) {
        //This person's last name matches the string aString
        [resultArray addObject: lastName];
    }

}

//print contents of array
for(NSString *lastName in resultArray) {
    NSLog(@"Last Name: %@", lastName);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i updated the code. Can you look it over again, and please tell me what i am doing wrong.